# XNA games C# application executable work on one win7 not the other one

Tags: shaders, directx11, xna-4.0, xna-content-pipeline

Our company wrote a game in XNA studio 4 almost ten years ago. we try to reinstall it in win7 with only the executable. Both installed XNA Game Studio 4.0. Below is the environments parameter I can find. The one on the laptop is not rendering the effect(I am new to this, this is my guess).

|  | Laptop | Desktop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OS | win7 Service Pack1 | win7 Service Pack1 |
| DirectX version | 11 | 11 |
| Graphic Card | AMD firepro M4000 Mobility Prographics | integrated GPU Intel HD graphics 4600 |
| Chip Type | AMD FirePro(0x682D) | Intel(R) HD graphics family |

We don't know what make these two executable behave differently. Part of the window image just not shown. Second check on the source code, the different between the image that can be show and can not be shown on the failed Laptop is working one is using Bitmap and the not working on is using Texture2D with  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics Effect with passes. Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote the game, any chance you could recompile the game in debug mode and debug it on that faulty machine? In any case, "not working" is never a good way to describe an issue.

Comment: When you say "not working" you really need to describe what's going wrong.

Comment: It's not rendering. I am new to this. I think maybe the effect is not rendering. We are not able to see graph as the working one. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please update with a thorough description: Was it newly installed on both machines or just on the laptop? Don't guess about the directx versions - check them with `dxdiag`. You said the laptop is newly installed - did you make sure all the graphics drivers got updated? Without more info, you're basically asking for people to guess about what might be wrong.

Comment: Could be requiring .NET install or DirectX 9.0

Comment: That's helpful, but I think you may have some errors. It seems really odd that the laptop would have a card type of Intel & a chip type of AMD - maybe you swapp columns by mistake there? Also, I couldn't find anything on a Firepro M400 - I suspect that might be a typo & you meant M4000?
[DirectX feature support on Win7 depends on SP1](https://www.lifewire.com/determine-directx-version-and-shader-model-812997) - did you update the new install to SP1?

Comment: @Pikalek you are absolutely right. I swapped those two. what does it mean to update? The patches? Do you think graphic card matters in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if that's related to the problem or not. Something about the differences between the two machines is causing a problem. It could be any combination of different hardware, drivers, or libs. As explained in the link above, Dx11 & Shader Model 5 require SP1 on Win7. The older install of Win7 on the PC probably has been updated to SP1; the new install on the laptop might not have been updated. Systematically eliminating differences makes it more likely that you'll find & correct the problem.

Comment: @Pikalek thanks again, we checked both service pack is SP1 and I tried do the various compatibility mode to launch the exe too. Neither of those work. Checked the XNA targets, DirectX lib, C++ distributable. Looks like only differ is graphic card. Went through the code, seems like bitmap works but when drawing with Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics Effect failed.

Comment: @Jay just checked .NET, which version? Should I look at the Multi-Targeting pack? DirectX9.0 run time been installed on both machine too.

Comment: @sandy Maybe check if there are any missing dependencies with a Windows dependency manager